# Does Rascal have a shorthand for integer max value or real max value?

Tags: rascal

Is there a shorthand in Rascal to get the max integer value?

e.g. in Java's Integer.MAX_VALUE, or C#'s Int32.MaxValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rascal does not have a maximum integer value; It just grows until you are out of memory.